# How to check $watch trigger in case of deep watching

Tags: angularjs

Say I am deep watching an object in AngularJS (I am using AngularJS 1.4). How can I check which property of the object triggered the $watch?

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.$watch('object',function(newVal,oldVal){
   if(newVal!=oldVal){
     if(Object.keys(newVal).length==Object.keys(oldVal).length){
       $scope.keyChanged=comparteValue(newVal,oldVal);
     }
   }
},true)

function comparteValue(object1,object2){
  var keyChange=null;
  angular.forEach(object1,function(val,index){
     if(val!=object2[index]){
       keyChange=index;
     }
  });
 return keyChange;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.simpleObject = { key1: 'someValue', key2:{subKey1:'test'}};

$scope.$watch('simpleObject.key1', function(newValue, OldValue){
// code here
});

$scope.$watch('simpleObject.key2.subKey1', function(newValue, OldValue){
// code here
});
```

But if you know where exactly the values get changed then you should use angularjs events by using  $on, $broadcasr & $emit